# yacca cca package: Error in cor(x, o$canvarx, use = use) : 'y' must be numeric

Tags: r

I am trying to use the `yacca` package to run a CCA analysis. Example code as follows:

```
library(yacca)
x <- matrix(data = rnorm(50*5), ncol=5)
y<- matrix(data = rnorm(50*10), ncol=10)
my_cca <- cca(x, y)
```

The error I get is:

> Error in cor(x, o$canvarx, use = use) : 'y' must be numeric.

I understand that the input to `cor` must be numeric. But, I believe my data to be numeric.  For example, `str(y)` (and `str(x)`) tells me:

> num [1:50, 1:5] 0.144 -0.392 0.464 -1.169 0.734 ...

And, `class(y)` (and `class(x)`) tells me:

> [1] "matrix" "array"

I believe that `o$canvarx` is the variable made via matrix multiplication, of x and x coefficients, as documented here: https://rdrr.io/cran/yacca/src/R/cca.R. But, I'm unsure of what might be going wrong. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know CCA but it seems that if `x` and `y` have the same dimentions, the code works. For instance, defining `y` as `matrix(data = rnorm(50 * 5), ncol = 5)`. Does it help? Does it make any sense to you?

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much. I did notice that, just now -- unfortunately, though, I'm not sure what to make of it. CCA does allow for the 'x' and 'y' sets to be differently sized (i.e., contain a differing number of  columns, representing variables/features), though the observations (rows) must be the same size. But perhaps that's a hint about what yacca is doing to the matrix (?).

Comment: Using `browser()` I noticed that complex numbers are being calculated. That's why it says `o$canvarx` must be numeric --that matrix right now is complex. The line generating complex numbers is this one: `ey <- eigen(qr.solve(cyy, cyx) %*% qr.solve(cxx, cxy))`. And those matrices are just covariance matrices: `cxx <- cov(x, use = use); cyy <- cov(y, use = use); cxy <- cov(x, y, use = use); cyx <- t(cxy)`. Again, no much idea about what's going on, but maybe using `browser()` and the source code with `yacca::cca` can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that, for some sets of input matrices, `eigen()` was producing solutions with very small (e.g., 1e-17) imaginary components.  These then caused problems for downstream functions that assumed real arguments, generating the error you saw.  (Odd that this hasn't surfaced in the past, and indeed when I ran your example but exchanged `x` and `y`, I didn't get the error.  But numerical noise can be very finicky.)  Anyway, a fix is now on github, so hopefully that resolves the issue!